# how to get 30 days from Todays

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime

```
Select from x
    WHERE yid = rid
    AND (h.test1 <=todaysdate) AND (h.test1>= 30 days from today)
```

How can I write that line **30 days from today** in a query?  Instead I put a date or a month from todays date.

Comment: use DateDiff function for getting the difference of 30days and pass the same in your query. `select DATEDIFF(DAY, '2012-03-21', GETDATE() )` this will return integer digit

Comment: ... wait, you're querying rows earlier than today AND more than 30 days in the future?

Comment: good point @dbaseman i did not checked that clearly..

Comment: i had a @CutOffDate which is today...but to select the last 30 days from today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can write:

```
SELECT * FROM x
WHERE yid=r=d 
      AND h.test1 <= todaysdate
      AND h.test1 >= ADDDATE(todaysdate, INTERVAL 31 DAY);
```

Are you sure anyway of your request?
Don't you want instead (dates before today or after 30 days):

```
SELECT * FROM x
WHERE yid=r=d 
      AND (h.test1 <= todaysdate
      OR h.test1 >= ADDDATE(todaysdate, INTERVAL 31 DAY));
```

or (dates between today and 30 days from today)

```
SELECT * FROM x
WHERE yid=r=d 
      AND h.test1 BETWEEN todaysdate AND ADDDATE(todaysdate, INTERVAL 31 DAY);
```

**EDITED after user comment**:
In MS SQL you can use

```
SELECT * FROM x
WHERE yid=r=d 
      AND h.test1 BETWEEN todaysdate AND DATEADD(dd, 30, todaysdate);
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM x
WHERE yid=r=d 
      AND h.test1 BETWEEN DATEDIFF(dd, 30, todaysdate) AND todaysdate;
```

Note that (as I've already told you in my comment) @dbaseman gave you correct syntax for adding days. Mine is just the correct query using that syntax.

**EDITED again after user comment:**

```
SELECT * FROM x
WHERE yid=r=d 
      AND h.test1 BETWEEN DATEDIFF(dd, 30, NOW()) AND NOW();
```

Comment: i think the question is not asked for mySQL then why is this answer posted here??

Comment: @Murtaza: OP tagged is question SQL... this does not mean neither MS-SQL, nor MySQL... I gave an answer for mysql, others can add other sql... :)

Comment: dates between todays and 30 days from todays

Comment: @Vadz: so take my last query if you're using MySql, else use @dbaseman one with `BETWEEN` syntax.

Comment: thanks Marco..but how to put that in SQL 2008 reports query..is it the same  as the one you just write?

Comment: @Vadz: I don't understand your comment, anyway I edited my answer again using `NOW()` function...

Comment: @Marco i use SQL 2008 reports

Comment: @Vadz: remember that you should [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) that solved (or helped to solve) your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Would help to know which SQL.  In MS SQL:

```
dateadd(dd, 30, todaysdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `BETWEEN` for brevity and `sysdate` for todays date in Oracle.

```
SELECT *
  FROM x
 WHERE yid = rid AND h.test1 BETWEEN TRUNC (SYSDATE) AND TRUNC (SYSDATE) + 30;
```

Comment: Nobody has asked answer in oracle.. please answer as required. dont confuse others.

Comment: @Murtaza sql server tag was not present at that moment i answered and i didn't knew on which platform it has to work.
So aswered it in oracle way.

Comment: is it the same as sql reports 2008?

Comment: no it is not. we need to use `datediff` or `dateadd` function for getting results between date in SQL