# Display dates not in database, only specific days of the week

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a sql database filled with specific dates for weekly training. We only have weekly training on Tuesdays and Wednesdays. It currently outputs like this:

```
Training Schedule

Mar 4 - Training Title
Mar 5 - Training Title
Mar 12 - Training Title
Mar 19 - Training Title
```

Well now I am being asked to show dates that aren't in the database as well but only Tuesday's and Wednesdays. So basically it has to look like this now.

```
Training Schedule

Mar 4 - Training Title
Mar 5 - Training Title
Mar 12 - Training Title
Mar 13 - No Training
Mar 19 - Training Title
Mar 20 - No Training
```

What is the best way to do this without going in and adding all the 'No Training' dates to the database (because that would take forever). Right now I'm simply just outputting the database results using the following code:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var tableSql = "select * from Training where Date >= " + "'" + now + "'" + " order by Date";
pcm.CommandText = tableSql;
prs = pcm.ExecuteReader();
var rowcount = 0;
while (prs.Read())
   {
     rowcount++;
          %>
 <%=Convert.ToDateTime(prs["Date"].ToString()).ToString("MMM d").ToUpper()%> - <%=prs["Title"].ToString().ToUpper() %> <% } %>
        <%
            prs.Close();
            pcn.Close();
        %>
```

Comment: can't you not just query the table based on the DayofTheWeek() Method? currently looks like you're querying all Dates that are >= Current System Date you will need to alter the Select Query

Comment: Start looking here for some ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901814/how-to-get-30-days-from-todays

Comment: I'm just confused on how the sql string is supposed to grab dates that don't exist in the database. None of the "No Training" dates are in the database.

Comment: if the dates are not in the table currently then how can you grab them. but if the dates moving forward are in there changing the query will benefit you.. however you could insert the dates yourself and test the query to see if the expected values are being returned this is what being a programmer is all about .. you can create your own test data I am quite sure

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the dataset returned by the SQL query and add the results to a collection (`List<string>`).  Then take your known date range and loop through those dates and if the day of week is Tuesday or Thursday, check your collection to see if there is a value for that date.  If so, display that string, if not, display the "No Training" message.